# WiX Toolset: Copy installation file to new directory

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.8, wix3.9

How can I get an actual path reference to the installation (.msi) file currently being executed?

I want to copy this file to a new location on disk.  I understand that I must use [CopyFile](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/copyfile.html) for this:

```
<Component Id="InstallationFileCopyId">
    <CopyFile Id="InstallationFileCopyId" FileId="{installation file}" DestinationDirectory="NewLocationDirectory" />
</Component>
```

I am using WiX Toolset 3.9 in Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wix has an `OriginalDatabase` property which shows the exact location of the msi being executed